# Yii2 Flash message not appear after redirect

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii-extensions, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I want to set flash message, but flash message missing if i add redirect. if i remove the line of redirect code then the flash message will be shown, but if i remove the redirect when i click on F5 refresh it will run again the file submission.
How to make redirect work together with the flash message?

the flow of my controller like this:

```
public function actionImportVehiclecsv()
    {
        $model = new CrmImportVehicle();
        $session = Yii::$app->session; // Get the session component
    
        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->csvVehicleFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'csvVehicleFile');
            $model->csvAccount = Yii::$app->request->post('CrmImportVehicle')['csvAccount'];
            
            if ($model->csvVehicleFile) {
                if ($filePath = $model->upload()) {
                    $processResult = $model->processVehicleFile($filePath);
                    
                    if ($processResult === true) {
                        $session->setFlash('success', 'CSV file uploaded and data inserted successfully.');
                    } elseif ($processResult === false) {
                        $session->setFlash('error', 'Error in CSV row: Vehicle No or Username cannot be blank');
                    } else {
                        $session->setFlash('error', $processResult); // Set error flash message for other errors
                    }
                    $session->set('processed', true); // Indicate that the form was processed
                } else {
                    $session->setFlash('error', 'Error uploading CSV file.');
                }
            } else {
                $session->setFlash('error', 'No file was uploaded.');
            }
    
            return $this->refresh(); // if i  remove this line, the flash message works.
        } elseif ($session->get('processed')) {
            $session->remove('processed'); // Clear the 'processed' flag for GET requests
            return $this->refresh(); // Refresh the page if it was previously processed
        }
    
        // Render the view for GET requests
        return $this->render('import-vehiclecsv', ['model' => $model]);
    }
```

Flash Message Appear if i remove the line of code
[image]

Flash Message missing if i add the refresh line code
[image]

Comment: I think you should not refresh the page ... Not sure but the flash message data uses session and stores the data for the next request only.

Comment: I agree with Govind that refreshing page when form is invalid is not best idea. If you refresh the page user will lose data they've entered into form and they need to fill whole form again instead of just fixing invalid fields.
On the other side flash message should survive single `$this->refresh()` call and should be displayed after refresh because that should be the "next request" in that case. I would try to check if there are more than 1 redirects when you submit invalid form.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of flash messages is in the principle that the message exists only for one request and are then deleted.

I would advise you to check whether you can retain the messages even after a refresh by using the `removeAfterAccess` parameter.

Source: [Yii documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-session#addFlash()-detail)

Answer (score -1):

`$this->refresh()` doesnt execute any additional server-side logic. Try using something like  `$this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer)`

Comment: `$this->refresh()` is pretty much just an alias for `$this->redirect($this->request->getUrl())`. So your suggestion doesn't rly solve anything.